# Not getting proper output from SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GetEmailForMailing] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @end int=1000
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT top(500) RegistrationID, EmailID from dbo.Candidate_RegistrationData
    where status_flag=1 and payment_status=2
    and RegistrationID NOT IN (SELECT top(@end) RegistrationID from dbo.Candidate_RegistrationData
    where status_flag=1 and payment_status=2) order by RegistrationID
END
```

This is my stored procedure. In this I want rows from 500 but I am getting from 250 row number.... any one have idea why it happen...thank you

Comment: You mean to say, first @end registration will be skipped? order by registrationID ascending ?

Answer (score 3):

The subquery used as the source of data for the `NOT IN` does not have an `ORDER BY` clause.  As a result, the query engine is free to take the `TOP(@end)` rows in whichever order it sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to skip **top @end** registration, **Order By RegistrationID**

You should try below code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GetEmailForMailing]   

@end int = 1000  

AS  

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
    Select Top(500) RegistrationID, EmailID From
    (
         Select Row_Number() Over(Order by RegistrationID) as RowId, 
                   RegistrationID,     
                   EmailID,    
                   status_flag, 
                   payment_status
         From dbo.Candidate_RegistrationData
         Where status_flag = 1 and payment_status = 2
    )T
    Where RowId > @end and status_flag = 1 and payment_status = 2 
    Order By RegistrationID
End
```